# JavaScript onClick adds form fields with drop down I need populated with PHP MySQL query

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript function that adds another line to the form when the user clicks on a button. I need a drop down added to this line that queries a mySQL DB to load data for company.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" class="center tmid" value="Add New Line" id="add_btn" name="add_btn" onclick="newLine(<?php echo $rowId; ?>, 'timecard')">
```

JavaScript:

```
function newLine(a,page) { 

  if (page == 'timecard') {
    //get total rows in the table and subtract the header row
    var rowCount = $('#tsTable tr').length;
    var i = rowCount - 1; 

    var rowId = parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(i);
    var tcId = this.tcId.value;

    $.get('functions/getCompany.php', function(result){
      var companyList = result;     
    });

    //create new row data       

     var newRowData = '<tr><input name="tcdid[]" type="text" value="'+rowId+'"><td><input type="date" name="jobDate[]" id="date'+rowId+'" value=""></td><td><input type="text" class="input-short" name="hours[]" id="h'+rowId+'" value=""></td><td><input type="text" class="input-short" name="ot[]" id="ot'+rowId+'" value=""></td><td><input type="text" class="input-short" name="km[]" id="km'+rowId+'" value=""></td><td class="nopadding"><select name="company[]" id="company'+rowId+'"></td><td><input type="text" name="ticket[]" id="ticket'+rowId+'" value=""></td><td><input type="text" name="wo[]" id="wo'+rowId+'" value=""></td><td><input type="text" name="details[]" id="d'+rowId+'" value=""></td><td class="td-shorter" ><input type="button" value="X" name="delete" class="btnDelete" onclick="deleteTimeLine(this,'+ rowId +',0)"></td></tr>';           

    //append new row to bottom of the table
    $(newRowData).appendTo($("#tsTable tbody"));
}
```

PHP:

```
function getCompany() {
    global $conn;
    $sqlC ="SELECT companyName 
            FROM customers 
            ORDER BY companyName ASC";
    $resultC = $conn -> query($sqlC);

    if($resultC === false){
        user_error("Query failed: ".$conn->error."<br />".$resultC);
        return false;
    }

    while ($companies = $resultC->fetch_assoc()) {              
        echo '<option value='.$companies['companyName'].'>'.$companies['companyName'].'</option>';
    }
}
```

So I would like to add the company drop down populated with the results in the getCompany() function. How would I go about this? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would normally do this using an AJAX call on the javascript side:

```
$.get('/path/to/file.php', function (result) {
    console.log(result); // do something with result returned
}
```

Then on the php side:

```
<?php // /path/to/file.php

// perform your query, set variables

if ($success) {
    echo json_encode([
        'status' => 'success',
        'html' => '<option value='.$companies['companyName'].'>'.$companies['companyName'].'</option>'
    ]);
}

echo json_encode([
    'status' => 'error',
    'message' => 'Something went wrong, handle this'
]);
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! I ended up adding your JavaScript portion and then added all the drop down options to a variable and then printed it via json_encode. I also did have to add the unescaped slashes flag. 
 echo json_encode($companyList,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);